How to generate a p12 with javascript generated key pair and server side internal CA
I'm working on a client-certificate based authentication of users for a website.
The server configuration part is OK
(Apache server, keywords: SSLCACertificateFile / SSLVerifyDepth / SSLVerifyClient optional)
The server code part is OK too:

I'm getting the client certificate's data (serial, DN etc),
if the user is logged in (login+password), he's proposed to register the client-certificate his browser provided
if he does, he won't need to enter login+password again, his client-certificate will be his open sesame
(based on testing client certificate serial/DN against serial/DN stored into DB at registering time).
he is free to unregister the certificate anytime from within his profile page, he just has to be logged in (even from a browser without certificate, with log+pass).

So far, so good.
Now I'd like to simplify the process for the users, so they don't have to bother creating/purchasing their certificates.
I'd like to let them download a certificate from an internal CA.
I'm not totally sure about the way I imagine this process, as described below:

a "generate client certificate"  button is proposed for logged in users
on click, a key pair is generated client side, using Web Crypto API: crypto.subtle.generateKey()
the public key is then ajax-sent to the browser
... here some server side magic (1) ...
the server returns a certificate signed by a dedicated internal intermediate CA,
... here some client side magic (2) ...
the user now has a .p12 keystore containing the downloaded certificate and the private key (which has never been sent outside of the client).
he just has to install it in his browser (or host system)

About "magic (1)" :
I want the CSR generation done server side.
But I don't have the client private key to sign the CSR.
I've read here and there, it's not a problem, I can sign a CSR with a dummy private key, then generate the final certificate from this CSR using the force_pubkey flag
(e.g. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/185202)
So this is my first question: is this practice acceptable? otherwise what are the security risks involved?
I mean, nobody should be able to do anything with this certificate except my user, who is the only one having the private key corresponding to this certificate... any security flaw I haven't seen here?
About "magic (2)":
At that point, I have:

the locally generated private key, strictly kept locally
its corresponding public key, which we previously sent to the server
a certificate for this public key, signed server side by the internal CA
Now I haven't found anything yet, neither on Mozilla's Web Crypto API documentation nor anywhere else, about this apparently simple question:
How can I, with javascript, gather the private key and the certificate together into a .p12 or .pfx keystore?


Here the answer I received on security stack: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/279910/340115 . Not sure if I best delete my question here or quote this as a self answer...
